# I want to install google-chrome-stable

Tags: google-chrome

```
root@mcdartey-hp-g56-notebook-pc:/home/mcdartgey# dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 221126 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (51.0.2704.63-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: dpkg by itself doesn't resolve dependencies. use gebi or ubuntu-software

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Answer (score 3):

Running:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Should resolve all dependency issues.